# regular expression to find in-between content

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the content between ***%%EndPageSetup***  and  ***LH(%%[Page: 1]%%) =*** using regular expression. I tried various patterns but not getting the correct output. Can someone please help me on this?

> %EndPageSetup
>
> /DeviceGray dup setcolorspace
>   /colspABC exch def ‹    …    scol
>   … „A VM? Pscript_WinNT_Incr begin
>   %%BeginResource: file Pscript_T42Hdr
>   5.0 0 /asc42 0.0 d/sF42{/asc42 ~ d Ji}bind d/bS42{0 asc42 -M}bind
>   d/eS42{0 asc42 neg
>   -M}b/Is2015?{version cvi 2015 ge}bind d/AllocGlyphStorage{Is2015?{!}{{string}
>   forall}?}bind d/Type42DictBegin{25
>   dict `/FontName ~ d/Encoding ~ d 4
>   array astore cvx/FontBBox ~
>   d/PaintType 0 d/FontType 42
>   d/FontMatrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]d
>   /CharStrings 256 dict`/.notdef 0 d &
>   E d/sfnts}bind d/Type42DictEnd{& @
>   /FontName get ~ definefont ! E}bind
>   d/RDS{string currentfile ~ readstring
>   !} executeonly
>   d/PrepFor2015{Is2015?{/GlyphDirectory
>   16 dict d sfnts 0 get @ 2 ^
>   (glyx)putinterval 2 ^(locx)putinterval
>   ! !}{! !}?}bind d/AddT42Char{Is2015?
>   {findfont/GlyphDirectory get ` d E !
>   !}{findfont/sfnts get 4 ^ get 3 ^ 2 ^
>
> LH(%%[Page: 1]%%) =

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some example input and output?

Comment: ...and what were the "various patterns" you tried that did not work?

Comment: Why the "close()" vote. It seems like a valid question with some precise answers?

Comment: Except there is no "Page: 1" in the provided example text, so any correct regex would return null on this text. Typo perhaps?

Comment: Thanks James for pointing that out. edited.

Comment: @RichardH, the sample text is PostScript.

Answer (score 1):

this may work

```
/EndPageSetup(.*?)LH\((?:.*?)\[Page: 1\](?:.*?)\) =/
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with your examples

```
%%EndPageSetup(.*?)\(%%\[.*?Page.*?\]%%\) =
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u1j7)

make sure to activate the `s` (dotall) modifier, so that is possible to match newline characters with the `.`.

Your result is then in capture group 1.

How to activate the modifier and how to get the result depends on your language.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(?:%%EndPageSetup)(.*\n)*(?=LH\(%%\[Page: 1\]%%\) =)
```

## Explanation

- The 3rd capture group `(?=LH\(%%\[Page: 1\]%%\) =)` uses a positive lookahead, so you can match that group without including it in the result.
- The 2nd capture group `(.*\n)` matches all characters including line breaks. Using `*`, you can match 0 or more of the preceding token/group.
- The first non-capturing group matches `(?:%%EndPageSetup)`and omits it from the result.

## Note

You can use lookbehinds too, but JavaScript doesn't support them.